# File Names of Quick Access Toolbar Icons

Tags: excel, vba, icons, toolbar, ribbon

A google search was no help in trying to determining the filename of the icon found in Excel's quick access toolbar modify options. Specifically looking for the icon file name for the <<< >>> ABC icon below.

I'm designing a custom ribbon in excel for distribution of vba code.. I want to use this icon but I do not have the name of it to use. For example, the name of the commonly seen calculator icon is access by the code below:

```
  Case "bButton01": RibbonImage = "Calculator"
```

[image]

What is the name of the <<<>>> ABC icon??? or the names of any of the quick access toolbar icons for that matter???

Thanks;

Comment: https://bert-toolkit.com/imagemso-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to find out...

1. Assign the icon to (eg) a macro on your Quick Access Toolbar
2. Use the `Import/Export` button to Export your menu customizations to a file
3. Open the file in a text editor, find that menu item and find the icon assignment attribute: in this case it's  `imageMso="HappyFace"`

[image]